# Range("A" & val ":A" & val2).Select

Tags: vba, excel

I am using inputbox for Val and Val2 values. These values i have to give in range of values but the syntax is showing incorrect.

Please correct me. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an & after val